# Get the elements which have different value in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Say you have two arrays of user roles and their status (on or off).

```
$current = array(1 => true, 2 => false, 3 => false, ...);
$wanted  = array(1 => true, 2 => true,  3 => false, ...);
```

Is there a PHP function to get an array with the difference between those two? In this case I would want to end up with this:

```
array(2 => true, ...);
```

Tried `array_diff` and `array_diff_assoc`, but those just checks if the keys or values exist, and they will of course exist in both.

Comment: How about old good `foreach`?

Comment: What's wrong with `array_diff_assoc($wanted, $current)` ?

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Fcvj48

Comment: @salathe Hm, very good question... no clue why I couldn't get it to work before, cause array_diff_assoc works perfectly now :/ Time for bed I suppose... If you make an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you tried, but you must have used `array_diff_assoc()` incorrectly.

```
$current = array(1 => true, 2 => false, 3 => false);
$wanted  = array(1 => true, 2 => true,  3 => false);
$diff    = array_diff_assoc($wanted, $current);
// array(2 => true)
```

Comment: Yeah, not sure what I've been up to. Thanks for answering anyways. Code sure got a lot cleaner with this, hehe.